# Angularjs defining template variable according to $state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

So I have something along the lines of:

```
<span>{{ $root.page_header || "default" }}</span>
```

But I'd like it to be **default** as long as the `$state` name is anything but a particular `$state`.

So in a logical sense, if I had the states: *home*, *settings*, & *profile*, I'd like `$root.page_header` to be **default** as long as the $state is not on **home**. And if it is home, I'd have my controller define what `$rootScope.page_header` is -- if that makes any sense.

I'm thinking I need to figure out how to get the $state name first and then add it somehow to my `{{ }}`.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: does $state.current.name return the state name you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do the logic on the view, you can use the javascript's inline if statement [Conditional (Ternary) Operator].

```
<span>{{ $root.page_header == 'home' ? $root.page_header : "default" }}</span>
```

Else if you want it in your controller
assign the page_header like this

```
$scope.page_header = $root.page_header == 'home' ? $root.page_header : "default";
```

then use it in the view

```
<span>{{page_header}}</span>
```

or

```
<span ng-bind="page_header"></span>
```

By the way I think you can get the state name by

```
$scope.page_header = $state.current.name;
console.log($scope.page_header)
```